# Xdebug with PhpStorm/Idea and Symfony in docker-compose: Breaks only at first file index_dev.php

Tags: php, symfony, docker, xdebug

I am using Idea Ultimate with PHP plugin.
`phpinfo()` seems ok and I have validated the configuration with the idea script.

[image]

The request used is `http://localhost:8080/web/index_dev.php/create-file`. I can put a breakpoint anywhere in index_dev() or use xdebug_break();

But I can't stop one file later, such as the Symfony controller.

I have a message saying `Debug session was finished without being paused` and propose a mapping between the docker instance and my local volume.

[image]

Looks fine to me, and it's able to find the `index_dev.php` inside this main directory.

So where can be the problem ?

Comment: Is your controller even executed?

Comment: yes. The page is displayed corrrectly

Comment: 1) Any symbolic links anywhere in the path? 2) What Xdebug log has to say about such unsuccessful debug session? 3) Show PHP Debug settings page from PhpStorm. Try disabling "break at first line" kind of option and see if it will stop at all (even where it was stopping before). If it does not stop (and overall so far) it looks like some path mapping issue.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to check IP address, I assume you're on linux.
So try to make

```
ifconfig
```

And then, find the line "docker0", take the "inet" value. Replace you remote host value with it. Usually the docker ip address is something like "172.17.0.1".

Please, also check that you have define idekey in your docker Xdebug Configuration

```
idekey=PHPSTORM
```

So change it and try to run again.

If it doesn't solve your issue, consider  configuring properly the xdebug remote server in PHPStorm.

- In **Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug**: change
     default port to 9000
- Create a server in **Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP >
     Servers**  with these info

  1. Name : whatever you want
  2. Host: Your app Host (mine is often "localhost")
  3. Port : you app port (mine  80)
  4. Click "Apply" then "OK"
  5. Close Settings
- Now you have to configure the remote debug which is going to listen
  to connection

  1. On PHPSTORM top left, click on "**Edit Configuration**"
  2. Click on **+** and select **PHP Remote Debug**
  3. Enter whatever the name you want
     4 Server: Select the previous server created in Settings Panel
  4. Enter **IDE_KEY: PHPSTORM**
  5. Click "Apply" then "OK"
  6. Then click on the little "beetle" (when pass your mouse over, it's pop out "**Debug '{name of remote server you define previously}'**"
  7. Add a breakpoint in first line of the controller you want to debug
  8. In your browser, go to the matching route
  9. Then magic happens !!!!!

Hope it helped you.